# Open file with VLC without adding to playlist?

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists

When I open WAV files individually from Windows Explorer to open in VLC, it adds each newly open file to the VLC playlist instead of simply discarding the previous file and playing a new one.

How do I get VLC to NOT behave this way?  When I open a new file, I want the previous one to be discarded/closed.